# can a user be part of multiple subtree in a (Ldap based) Directory Service instance?

Tags: .net, ldap, directoryservices, ldap-query

I am pretty new to the ldap based directory service programming using .net framework; hence have a basic silly question.

I would like to find out the all sub trees a particular user belongs to using System.DirectoryServices.Protocol.

First of all, can a User be part of the multiple Sub Trees in “a” directory service instance?  If yes, then how can I find all the sub trees that a particular user belongs to using “System.DirectoryServices.Protocol “ namespace?

If a user belongs to “only” a particular sub tree, then I guess I can find all the DN of the sub tree from the DN of the user. Please let me know if there is any other efficient way?

Update:

To be specific  about my question , given this is DN of my user object - “uid=DaffyD,OU=Ducks,OU=People,O=A “  ,  whether can it exist in other OU directly or indirectly? E.g.  can “OU=Ducks” be part of any other OU than “People”?

Then my next question, without doing some kind of string manipulation of user’s DN , can I somehow find the names of parent nodes’ DN that this user using System.DirectoryService.Protocol efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a user "belonging" to a subtree. A *user object* will exist in a single path in the directory, and its DN will tell you what that path is (in practice, it's vice versa: you know the DN and then find the object). This is the whole point of the DN == distinguished name: to uniquely name objects.

Of course, a user can belong to multiple groups (as a feature of Active Directory); those groups are spread over the directory. Not sure whether you also referred to groups when using the word "belong".

Edit: as any kind of user object can only have a single parent OU, likewise, each OU can have only a single parent container (typically O or OU). The entire directory forms a tree, no node can have two parents.

The framework only processes DNs as strings. However, there are third-party [DN parser libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dnparser.aspx) available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what I am looking for right now is that Directory Service groups a user is  member  and possible subtrees that user is part of  - for example - "uid=DaffyD,OU=Ducks,OU=People,O=A" , DaffyD is part of "OU=Ducks,OU=People,O=A"  and "OU=People,O=A" and "O=A" subtree.

Hence, I was trying to find out all the parent nodes'DN that a user belongs to. Therefore, was wondering , except DN , can it be part of other subtree?...from your post i can see - it can't. 

Is there any way I can find out those without doing string manipulation on user DN ?

Comment: See my edit. The DirectoryServices framework does not support DN parsing.

Comment: To clarify, it should be noted that the only thing that is guaranteed by the LDAP spec, is that the DN is unique in a given directory. Any other attribute is not guaranteed to be. SO yes, you can have the exact same object in two differents OU in the directory. Some commercial directory add some specific checks to guarantee unicity of others attributes (for example samAccountName in AD).

Answer (score 3):

This is based solely on my experience with Active Directory - but I would assume other LDAP directories will handle it similarly:

No, a user exists only once and therefore can only be located in one single container (typically an OrganizationalUnit). There's no concept of "symbolic links" to users, as far as I know.

And why would you really want a user to exist in multiple places anyway??

If you want the user to be part of several subtrees in order to handle permissions, you're doing it all wrong - you shouldn't base your decisions whether or not to permit some user a given operation on his "location" in the LDAP hierarchy, but rather on group membership.

LDAP groups are what are intended to handle permissions, and a user can be member of any number of groups - there you have your 1:n relationship - user can be member of groups, and those groups are responsible for handling permissions.

Marc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually , I do not want a user to exist to multiple place. while building a generic solution, was wondering whether it is possible...seems like no.for a particular user , is there anyway i can find all the DN where any one could search & find this user with searchscope.subtree ? using system.directoryservices.protocol?